# ODE from systems biology, can I generalize this? Have solution but not sure how to arrive at it.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Reading a systems biology book, and it describes a model with the following ODE:

$$ \frac{dY}{dt} = -\gamma Y + v_1 X_1 (T - Y) + v_2 X_2 (T - Y)$$ where $Y$, $T$, $T - Y$, $X_i$, $a$ and $v_i$ are all greater than 0 .

The book gives the solution as $$\frac{Y}{T} = f(w_1 X_1 + w_2 X_2)$$ where $f(u) = \frac{u}{1+u}$ and $w_1 = \frac{v_1}{\gamma} $, $w_2 = \frac{v_2}{ \gamma}$

What I want to know is if this extends to the case of more than two $X_i$'s, i.e.:

if $$\frac{dY}{dt} = -\gamma Y + \sum_i^k v_i X_i (T - Y)$$

is the following the correct solution:

$$\frac{Y}{T} = f(\sum_i^k w_i X_i)$$

I tried to figure this out by trying to solve solve the $ \frac{dY}{dt} = -\gamma Y + v_1 X_1 (T - Y) + v_2 X_2 (T - Y)$ myself and seeing if I could generalize it, but couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: All of these are of the form $$Y'(t)=-AY(t)+B,$$ for some $(A,B)$ depending on the specifics of the problem. Each such equation is solved as $$\frac{AY'(t)}{B-AY(t)}=A=[-\log(B-AY(t))]'$$ hence $$B-AY(t)=(B-AY(0))e^{-At},$$ and finally, $$Y(t)=BA^{-1}+(Y(0)-BA^{-1})e^{-At},$$ which does not look like what you present in your question. Note that this holds with $$A=\gamma+\sum_iv_iX_i,\qquad B=T\sum_iv_iX_i.$$